# Pearson's theorem for cross table

Tags: chi-squared-test

In order to understand Person's theorem (why chi squared test is justified),
I have read this [lecture note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/896115b23d713bde212c45f62c086080_lecture11.pdf) and I think I understood the discussion, but I still don't understand why the degree of freedom for table size a*b becomes (a-1)*(b-1).
Could anyone explain to me?

Comment: Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi+squared+test+table+freedom+answers%3A1) for answers.

Comment: Not at all an answer, but the history is that Pearson just did not understand degrees of freedom and never forgave, and perhaps never really accepted, Fisher publishing what we now see as a correct analysis.